# What are the differences between the Shelley and Byron phases of Cardano?

Tags: byron, shelley

Is there anything of significance beyond Shelley is required for staking?

Comment: I think that the upcoming Vasil fork will bring us into the Basho era that introduce scalability to the current Goguen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the Shelley upgrade, Cardano became a fully decentralized and dynamic ecosystem. In the Byron era there were no stake pools (and therefore no staking) and the blockchain was run by the creators alone.

Answer (score 1):

I believe number of slots reserved in a single epoch is also increased in Shelley. In DBSync, syncing Shelley takes way too much time to sync compare to Byron era.

Comment: Yes, correct. Neverthless I think that the scope of the question was less technical al more tehorical.